# Illustrator basic: 3d grid view

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

[image: WHAT IS THAT]

Anyone knows how to hide this "3d grid looking" object? I must have used some smart shortcut.

Comment: Nice. I thought I've seached in view, but apparently not close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View > Perspective Grid > Hide`

Answer (score 0):

click on the `x` on the very top left perspective indicator.

[image]

Comment: i tried, but the icon was disapearing. Anyway the shortcut is **Shift** **Ctr** **I**